# Remembering a novel trilogy where the world hibernated. Girls seek "sun powers"

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember a novel from when I was younger. Oh about late 1980s to early 1990s. The book could be older than that. It just seems my Google-fu cannot break the author or title barriers.

The book I remember reading was actually an omnibus. I believe it came out about the same time as *The World of Tiers* and *The Book of Swords*. Of the stories in the omnibus, I remember three story parts.

The first story described a world where people hibernated during the winter that would last until the sun came again and lone girls would stay awake. The world itself, other than the hibernation, seemed more fantasy than sci-fi. These girls would take dangerous quests to see if they they had "sun powers". In all of this was a young boy who appeared at the castle and quickly learned things. He was a good person but he was actually a plant for a planet raiding pirate band. In the end the native girl and the pirate plant defeated the pirates leaving behind other clones of the boy who was also a clone of a traveller that was captured by the pirates years ago.

The second story in the omnibus described a daughter of these clones going out from the valley to find her father who had started living with the desert people. She too developed "sun powers" and the father had with him multicolored silks that their colors reflected equal emotions back at the wearer; red equals anger, etc. the silks also seemed to contain memories.

The third story in the omnibus describes the journey of the daughter from the first story going out on a quest to find the origins of these silks. In this she does and discovers creatures that weave silk, emotions, and memory all into each piece of silk. During this journey, she too develops "sun powers".

**Could someone identify this book?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the *Sunstone Scrolls* trilogy by Sydney Van Scyoc.

1. *Darkchild* (1982)
2. *Bluesong* (1983)
3. *Starsilk* (1984)

These have been collected in an omnibus, *Daughters of the Sunstone* (1985).

I believe she wrote a couple of short stories set in the same world:

- "Mountain Wings", published in *Asimov's Science Fiction* Nov. 1979
- "Darkmorning", published in *Asimov's Science Fiction* Mar. 1980
- "Stonefoal", published in *Asimov's Science Fiction* Aug. 1980

Comment: Thank you. These are exactly the ones I was looking for.

Comment: Additional sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_J._Van_Scyoc and http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1457 and http://www.tdl.com/~sjvan/sjvans.htm (which is her official homepage, according to WikiPedia).